# Explanation of defination of Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

While reading the book on Forms and connection ,I am stuck with following defination of manifold.I am stuck at the part after defining function $f$ for submersion. Can anyone explain me this defination using example? 
[image]

Comment: See chapter 5 from the book  Jhon M.Lee introduction to smooth manifold.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to see the submanifold as the solution to a system of $k$ equations with $n+k$ unknowns, at least locally. Requiring that $f$ be a submersion is asking that the equations not be redundant.

Consider the example of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$: you can think of it as the solutions to the equation $$ x^2 + y^2  = 1. $$
In this example you can take $U$ to be $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and your submersion to be $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1$.

Notice that the differential of $f$ is $2x dx + 2y dy$, which vanishes only at the origin, so this is a submersion.

We can consider a circle inside of $\mathbb{R}^3$ also, for instance, by taking a single set $U = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus ( \{ (0,0) \} \times \mathbb{R} )$ and taking 
$ f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2-1, z)$. The circle is then the set of points with $z=0$ and $x^2+y^2 = 1$.

Now, the idea of allowing yourself several open sets and several different submersions is that your submanifold might only look like this locally. 
(If it is globally obtainable by a submersion, it has what is called a trivial normal bundle. If the submanifold is something non-orientable, like a Klein bottle or real projective space sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^4$, you will need multiple open sets and multiple functions. There are other examples, as discussed in this related question:
[Manifold embedded in euclidean space with nontrivial normal bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108467/manifold-embedded-in-euclidean-space-with-nontrivial-normal-bundle/108481#108481))

Comment: Great answer!! One question. What does the statement $$""U \cap M=f^(-1)(0)$$?

Comment: @Abhi7731756 it's mean you can see your submanifold locally as level sets for some submersion (it's a one criteria of proving a set is submanifold).

Comment: @Abhi7731756, are you asking what the notation $f^{-1}(0)$ means? It means the set of points $\{ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0 \}$. I'm thinking of this as the set of solutions to the equation $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0$.

The statement $U \cap M = f^{-1}(0)$ then means that the part of $M$ that is in the open set $U$ is given by set of points that have $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0$.